# How to get text from a div by val()

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am using Jquery UI for **tabs**. In each tab i have a empty div. I have a textarea outside the tabs in which i give values to store in those empty divs.

The problem is i have fixed the value to "Null" so that i can refresh textarea when i change between tabs.

But the problem is i have to keep the value of tab and display it in text area when we change to the previous tab.

I used the script

```
$(function() {
    $( "#tabs" ).tabs();
});
$(function() {
  $("#t1").unbind("click").click(function()
    {
    $('#custom_text').val("");
    $("#custom_text").unbind("keyup").keyup(function()
        {
    $('#tab1').text('').append($("#custom_text").val()); 
    });
});
  });
 $(function() {
  $("#t2").unbind("click").click(function()
    {
$('#custom_text').val("");
    $("#custom_text").unbind("keyup").keyup(function()
   {
    $('#tab2').text('').append($("#custom_text").val()); 

    });
});
  });
$(function() {
$("#t3").unbind("click").click(function()
    {
$('#custom_text').val("");
    $("#custom_text").unbind("keyup").keyup(function()
    {
    $('#tab3').text('').append($("#custom_text").val()); 

        });
});
});
```

And My HTML is

```
<div id="tabs">
<ul>
    <li id="t1"><a href="#tabs-1">TAB 1</a></li>
    <li id="t2"><a href="#tabs-2">TAB 2</a></li>
    <li id="t3"><a href="#tabs-3">TAB 3</a></li>
</ul>
<div id="tabs-1">
    <p>TAB 1 CONTENT</p>
  <div id="tab1"></div>
</div>
<div id="tabs-2">
    <p>TAB 2 CONTENT</p>
   <div id="tab2"></div>
</div>
<div id="tabs-3">
    <p>TAB 3 CONTENT</p>
   <div id="tab3"></div>
</div>


</div>
<textarea id="custom_text" rows="5" cols="30"></textarea>
```

I have made a [BIN](http://jsbin.com/ifeyif/1/). Kindly assist me where i am making error in the program

Comment: Why does `$(function() {...});` close after just one line of active code?

Comment: I am using codes from two different files here thats the reason

Comment: If the other lines are really inside their own `$(function() {...});` structure, then I suggest editing the code to show that.

Comment: @Beetroot-Beetroot i have updated the question check now...

Comment: Your question is not really clear: "The problem is i have fixed the value to "Null" so that i can refresh textarea when i change between tabs. But the problem is i have to keep the value of tab and display it in text area when we change to the previous tab." What is meant exactly by that? What you mean by "refreshing" the text area? Either you want to set it to "null", ie. empty, or you want to display the same characters that are also in the div. Both is not possible.

Comment: Vivek, what are you actually trying to achieve? What do you want to happen that is not already coded?

Comment: Leave it friends @AdtianBer solved it http://jsbin.com/ifeyif/22/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I got this right, you want the textarea to be populated with the value of the tab entered before. If so, replace line

```
$('#custom_text').val("");
```

with

```
$('#custom_text').val($("#tab1").text());
```

and do this for all the tabs.

Comment: What you can also improve is to write the same code for all tabs instead of duplicating it three times.

Answer (score 1):

You seems to be missing `$(document).ready` in your jQuery function. And also you need to provide $("#t1").ready(function() because t1 is the default tab rendered without a click. So, modify your `script` part like this:

```
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" />
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://jqueryui.com/resources/demos/style.css" />
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $( "#tabs" ).tabs();

        $("#t1").ready(function()
        {
            $('#custom_text').val("");
            $("#custom_text").unbind("keyup").keyup(function()
            {
                $('#tab1').text('').append($("#custom_text").val()); 
            });
        });

        $("#t1").unbind("click").click(function()
        {
            $('#custom_text').val("");
            $("#custom_text").unbind("keyup").keyup(function()
            {
                $('#tab1').text('').append($("#custom_text").val()); 
            });
        });

        $("#t2").unbind("click").click(function()
        {
            $('#custom_text').val("");
            $("#custom_text").unbind("keyup").keyup(function()
            {
                $('#tab2').text('').append($("#custom_text").val()); 
            });
        });

        $("#t3").unbind("click").click(function()
        {
            $('#custom_text').val("");
            $("#custom_text").unbind("keyup").keyup(function()
            {
                $('#tab3').text('').append($("#custom_text").val()); 
            });
        });
    });
    </script>
</head>
```

Comment: OK, I didn't understand your question. But I think `$("#t1").ready(function() ` is still needed for initializing t1 without a click.